# is it possible to detect that someone has used a VPN after the VPN has been disabled?

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm asking this question because I am using a VPN for work and apparently Tera Online servers ban users for using VPN. I've asked their support about what if I disable it and try logging in, and their answer was:

> After using a VPN and disabling it, you have to wait for a security
>   time of 24 hours to be able to access your account again.

That sounds like a load of bullshit to me. After all, the VPN is disabled, how could they possibly detect that I've used it several hours after disabing it?

So the question is - is it really possible, and if so, why, aswell as - is 24 hours a realistic period of time? I could understand maybe half an hour, max 1 hour, but a WHOLE day...

Comment: What do you mean by "realistic period of time"?

Comment: Frankly - it's their line, you chose their service, you signed the deal. As to what is reasonable, maybe a court would be able to decide, but I'm sure we can't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Their server would know the IP of your VPN provider. They probably compare this to a list of known VPN providers. They can use your account to associate your old VPN session with your VPN-less session, and decline the login.

Comment: But my IP should go back to normal once I disable the VPN, shouldn't it? If so, then them comparing my IP with the VPN IP should return false right after I disable it.

Comment: Yes, but they will have records of your VPN-ip from your previous connection.

Comment: But my current IP will have changed, so the comparison will be false... Isn't that how it works? Or does the VPN-IP equal my normal IP?

Comment: Your first statement is correct, but presumably you're loging-in with the same account. They will match based on that, find that the account logged in from a banned VPN-IP some time-period ago, and decline the login. (I assume)

Comment: Yeah, that's logical apart from the "decline the login" part. It doesn't make sense to ban someone AGAIN if the current connection is NOT from a VPN just because they connected with a VPN some time ago. That's just rubbing it in their face.

Comment: I'm not in a position to comment on that really. The answer is "it's possible". As to _why_ they do it, you'd have to ask them.

Comment: @jurchiks - It might not be logical does not mean they don't do it.  Let us keep the question on topic.

Comment: If I have used a VPN and during that time have NOT accessed my Tera account, then disabled the VPN and tried logging in to my Tera account, they should not be able to detect that I have used the VPN, because *I wasn't using their services while on VPN*. And even if they can detect that for some reason, banning for that is retarded to say the least.